# How to recover data via adb?

Tags: adb, restore, huawei

My phone is huawei u8800 and it keeps restarting as soon as opened. Now it is closed and in adb, I tried

```
adb backup -all
```

but it gave the error

```
now unlock your device and confirm the backup operation
```

I don't want to lose data. What can I do?

I have CWM, I have backed up but I can't trust that if I reset, it can restore my data.

I can't open the phone so I cant use backup programs.

Comment: Problem is, even with `adb backup`, you need to at least tap one button on the device to confirm – a security measure, so a "data thief" cannot simply "dump" your stuff. // What do you mean by "opening"? Does it hang in a boot-loop, or does it reboot when you unlock the screen?

Comment: As soon as it loads beginning screen, it restarts. I can npt even unlock the screen. Sometimes it restarts without loading desktop.

Comment: Along with CWM, did you install a custom ROM (like CyanogenMod or MIUI, for example?)

Comment: Yes i installed aurorasp and after that restarting started (i did not install any update or apps but restarting started) , i reflashed some roms to solve without wiping data. It  did not work. Once, restarting was delayed, 4-5 seconds.

Comment: When installing a *different* ROM, not wiping can lead to trouble – like you experience now. Did you create a backup before flashing? Hopefully even Nandroid? In that case, the best approach would be restoring that, then do your `adb backup` (*excluding system stuff!*), and after a clean wipe/flash you can restore your apps and data from it. For "system data" (contacts, calendars, APNs, etc) you will have to take care separately. Please also check our [backup tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info).

Comment: No, after this problem started, i tried to install new roms without wiping to solve that.